# Blood lactate and glucose

Tags: exercise, anaerobic, lactate-threshold

When you exercise blood lactate levels tend to increase as a function of intensity. At the same time, I have seen in a few research [papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23738629) that blood glucose levels tend to drop as lactate increases

What is the relationship between lactate and glucose? Why is there an inverse relationship between the two?